# Nullable Reference Types usage in classes with temporally nullable fields

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

In my following elaboration I am referencing to the new feature of [Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) introduced in C# 8.

I ask me very often, whether I should or not decorate this or that reference type property nullable (eg. `object? prop { get; }` or `[MaybeNull] T prop { get; }`)

I would like to show you the class that gives me a headache.

```cs
public sealed class LinkedBucketListNode<KeyType, ValueType>
    where KeyType : notnull
{
    public ValueType Value { get; }

    public LinkedBucketListNodePart ListPart { get; }
    public LinkedBucketListNodePart BucketPart { get; }
    public YetNullable<KeyType> Key => bucket.Key;

    public ILinkedBucketList<KeyType, ValueType>? Bucket => bucket; // <------- Declare as nullable or not????

    internal LinkedBucketListBase<KeyType, ValueType>.LinkedBucket bucket = null!;

    public LinkedBucketListNode(ValueType value)
    {
        ListPart = new LinkedBucketListNodeListPart(this);
        BucketPart = new LinkedBucketListNodeBucketPart(this);
        Value = value;
    }

    internal void Invalidate()
    {
        ListPart.Invalidate();
        bucket = null!;
        BucketPart.Invalidate();
    }

    ...
}
```

This sealed class `LinkedBucketListNode<KeyType, ValueType>` has one of the SAME  behaviour like `LinkedListNode<T>`:

1. Instantiate outside of LinkedBucketList
2. Add via AddLast, AddFirst, ... to a LinkedBucketList of your choice.
3. If getting invalidated due to remove, `bucket` gets null and is disconnected from bucket.

So you are going to expect `bucket` being null before you add the node and after you remove the node.

Now to my question. Is it appropiate to mark `LinkedBucketListNode<KeyType, ValueType>.Bucket` as nullable reference type or should I expect from the user, that he should now that `LinkedBucketListNode<KeyType, ValueType>.Bucket` will be null before adding and after removing it and dismiss it as expected API-behaviour?

Comment: `new object[] { null, null, null }` what value do you think `Current` will have?

Comment: [`IEnumerator`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/F/workspace/_work/1/s/bin/repo/runtime/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/IEnumerator.cs/IEnumerator.cs,6624f38cb955bfe0) source

Comment: I see, it is not the best example, because you define what T is. In this case you would simply use IEnumerator<object?> because any value of any index could be null. My point is, you have access to an variable which is API-specific null (bucket of node before add, bucket of node after remove,. Should this bucket be decorated as nullable or not, because you would know that bucket can only be not-null if it is attached to bucket.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the specifics of your business logic, but as a general rule: You should only use `object` or `[NotNull] object` if your properties will _never_ be `null` after initialization—or very shortly after, if they're being initialized by e.g. a factory method or deserializer that ensures they'll be populated. If at any point after that they may be `null` based on standard usage of your class, such as removing a bucket, then they should be marked as `object?` or `[MaybeNull] object`. The question you want to ask: Should consumers of your class defensively check for null?

Comment: To your formulated question: Correct. I asked me that, because it is pretty "annoying" to decorate everything with (or at least the first occurence in same block) with `!` even when I could know, that it cannot be null. So yes, I follow your idea, to decorate everything with MaybeNull, when properties will ever can get null after initialization. Thanks for taking your time. :)